# You may need to add 'www.example.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS (but it is there)

Tags: django, dns, webfaction

As title shows, I get the 
`You may need to add 'www.example.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS` ...  (but it is there)

Trying another approach, I simply put `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` which if I am not mistaken allows any host, and should solve the issue for all hosts, but same error is thrown.

Is there any other common cause responsible for this that I should check? The only other possible issues I can think of:

- Domain propagation is still happening since its a new domain (though
  I can't fathom how it would affect this, since the website is
  reached)
- I am using the same app (webfaction) for two sites. Is it
  favoring one domain over the other?

Out of ideas beyond that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it **may take time to access using domain** even if you have made a redirection from your domain registrar to your server ip address.

**Try using server ip address:**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['121.57.20.34','www.example.com','example.com']
```

For now just try in your browser:

```
http://121.57.20.34/
```